# Mvc Identity Longin ClaimsPrincipal value always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-identity, principal

This is my Login controller

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {                                         
      var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] 
      {
         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Huang"),
         new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Vaild.ToString()),
         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,"xxx@gmail.com"),
         new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone,"123456"), 
      },DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);


  IdentityTool.Authentication(AuthenticationManager,identity,rememberMe:true);

     // userEmail and userPhone  always null and I got null exception
        var userEmail = CurrentUser.Email;
        var userPhone = CurrentUser.MobilePhone;  

    return View(model);
   }
}

public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public AppUser CurrentUser
    {
        get { return new AppUser(this.User as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal);}

    }
}
```

IdentityConfig

```
public class IdentityTool
{
 public static void Authentication(IAuthenticationManagerauthenticationManager, ClaimsIdentity identity, bool rememberMe)
     {
        if (rememberMe)
        {
            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(14)
            }, identity);
        }
        else
        {
            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                IsPersistent = false
            }, identity);
        }
    }
}

//Custom property
public class AppUser : ClaimsPrincipal
{        
    public AppUser(ClaimsPrincipal principal) : base(principal)
    {
    }
    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
        }
    }

    public string MobilePhone
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone).Value;
        }
    }
 }
```

This is my  Startup

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;                     
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType =DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, 
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {

            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });            
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Then I got null exception on "CurrentUser.Email" and "CurrentUser.MobilePhone" always null. Please help me to fix it. I really appreciate. I ask many people but no one can fix it.If you have some suggest to modify some code.May helpful.Please let me know.blow picture is my exception detail. Sorry for some Chinese in the picture.^^

[This is my exception detail hope help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8d3b.png)

Comment: have u romoved form authentication in web.config?

Comment: What you have in authenticationManager?

Comment: I didn't modify web.config. I need remove some code in web.config?

Comment: <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />

Comment: What you have in authenticationManager?   I don't what's mean I just use Mvc Identity few days. Please bear with me.

Comment: do you have like this authenticationManager =HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();\

Comment: Yes.I have HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUser‌​Manager>(); in account controller  and I try remove this code in my web.config  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />then I got the same error message.

Comment: I am really confused.Because I set up all condition still fail.I ask many people no one can fix it....

Comment: Add these at end of Authentication function---  ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

Comment: I try to add this code at end of Authentication function but still null...so confused

Comment: So you are getting error at this line  // userEmail and userPhone  always null and I got null exception
        var userEmail = CurrentUser.Email;
        var userPhone = CurrentUser.MobilePhone;

Comment: Man you put this line after this one     IdentityTool.Authentication(AuthenticationManager,identity,rememberMe:true);

Comment: sorry~userEmail and userPhone code actually  after line IdentityTool.Authentication(AuthenticationManager,identity,r‌​ememberMe:true);    I type worry. also I upload a picture. this picture include detail exception.hope helpful.

Comment: comment those two line instead of that try this----             var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);

Comment: I try your method.but I got null no exception. just null. I debug to see User.Identity Claim just one property.{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: } then value is ""

Comment: I really confused.Because my colleague write same code. they are success to read identity custom values.except me so strange...

Comment: try adding -- AuthenticationManager =  HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;   before this line ---- IdentityTool.Authentication(AuthenticationManager,identity,rememberMe:true);

Comment: I know your mean.but I got this method in account controller.private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }still got null and exception...

Comment: replace configure auth by this ---- public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;                     
    
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath =  new PathString("/Account/Login"),
              
            });}

Comment: I try it then I got the same error.I think I put values into to claimsIdentity success. but doesn't into ClaimsPrincipal. Just guess...

Comment: @PowerStar I solved this problem.But I don't understand the reason.I just add two line end of  Authentication function .
ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;